# Question based on complex differentiation?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, derivatives, complex-numbers, partial-derivative

**Question:**

If $ \Im[f'(z)]=6x(2y-1)$ and $f(0)=3-2i,f(1)=6-5i$

then, $f(1+i)=?$

**my attempt:**

i used property

${f'(z)=u_{1} (z,0)-i\ u_{2}(z,0)}$ where

$ u_{1} (x,y)=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}$  and

$u_{2} (x,y)=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$

i used Cauchy -Reimann equations also

but failed to get right answer ...please provide right way to approach ,thank you.

Comment: @ bames : yes,i'm sure  $ f(1)= 6-5i $

Comment: Yes, I forgot a constant in one of my differential equations. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$, where $z = x+iy$. Then $f'(z) = u_x + iv_x$, and $u,v$ must satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations:
$$u_x = v_y$$
$$u_y = -v_x$$
We are given that $v_x = 6x(2y-1) = -u_y$. Integrating, we find $v = 3x^2(2y-1) + \phi(y)$ and $u = 6x(y-y^2) + \psi(x)$, where $\phi(y), \psi(x)$ are arbitrary functions. Differentiating, we find:
$$u_x = 6(y-y^2)+\psi'(x)$$
$$v_y = 6x^2+\phi'(y)$$
It is now apparent that if $u_x = v_y$, then
$$\psi'(x) -6x^2=\phi'(y) + 6(y^2-y)$$
It follows that the right and left hand sides must be constant. We find that
$$\psi(x) = 2x^3 + C_0x+C_1$$
$$\phi(y) = 3y^2-2y^3 + C_0y + C_2$$
for constants $C_0,C_1, C_2$. So our $f(z)$ now looks like:
$$f(z) = 6x(y-y^2) + 2x^3 + C_0x  + C_1 +i(3x^2(2y-1) + 3y^2 - 2y^3 + C_0y + C_2)$$
We can identify the constants $C_0,C_1$ using the given values of $f$ at $0,1$. Since $f(0) = 3-2i$, $C_1 = 3$ and $C_2 = -2$. Since $f(1) = 6-5i$, $C_0 = 1$. Hence,
$$f(z) = 6x(y-y^2)+2x^3+x+3 + i(3x^2(2y-1)+3y^2-2y^3 + y -2)$$
Then $f(1+i)$ is:
$$f(1+i) = 6+3i$$

Comment: @ bames : your answer is absolutely correct , but i'm unable to understand how you find $\phi(y), \psi(x)$ from their derivatives ${\phi(y)}'$,$ {\psi(x)}'$   , i mean this line "It follows that right and left hand sides must be constant"

Comment: @veereshpandey The right and left hand sides must be constant, since the variables have been separated. This implies that $\psi'(x) -6x^2 = C_0$ and $\phi'(y) + 6(y^2-y) = C_0$ for some constant $C_0$. Rewriting these as $\psi'(x) = 6x^2 + C_0$ and $\phi'(y) = 6(y-y^2) + C_0$, we can then integrate them to find that $\psi$ and $\phi$ are as stated above.

Comment: @ bames : okay . got it !...thank you

Comment: @ bames : i think there is a 'typo' above, it should be  $\psi (x)=2x^{3}+C_{0}x+C_{1}$ but you've written $\psi (x)=3x^{2}+C_{0}x+C_{1}$, anyway below you've written correctly

Comment: @veereshpandey Yes, you're right. Sorry about that. I'll fix it now.